# How to make a dynamic JavaScript call using a PHP value and an Input value as inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to implement the following functionality to add more rows

[image]

but I am having a hard time figuring out how to to make the javascript call

```
<button onclick="buildTable(?????)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
```

The current number of rows is stored in a PHP variable `$rows` which was passed in on the previous `buildTable(1)` call

I need to add `$rows` to the value from the input box below (the lower '8' as seen below)

```
<input type="number" placeholder="1" name="moreRows">
```

How can I add $rows to moreRows and pass it in to the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getElementsByName()` to find the input element, get its value, and add that to the PHP variable.

```
<button onclick="buildTable(<?php echo $rows; ?> + parseInt(document.getElementsByName('moreRows')[0].value, 10))"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
```

Comment: What does the [0] mean?

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a list of all the elements with the name. `[0]` accesses the first element of the list.